# Открыть конкретный блок, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вопрос в следующем, имеется, допустим, 4 кнопки, при клике на кнопку текст в ней должен изменяться на "Открыто", сейчас же проблема в том, что если кликнуть на 1 кнопку, то текст изменится во всех кнопках, есть ли какое-нибудь элегантное решение для такой задачи? Никак не могу разобраться, спасибо.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          {open ? "Открыто" : "Закрыто"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          {open ? "Открыто" : "Закрыто"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          {open ? "Открыто" : "Закрыто"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          {open ? "Открыто" : "Закрыто"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас версия реакта 16.8.0 и выше, можно избавиться от классового компонента и использовать хук `useState` для менеджмента состояния кнопок:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    { open: false },
    { open: false },
    { open: false },
    { open: false }
  ]);

  const handleOpen = id => {
    const newButtons = buttons;
    newButtons[id].open = !buttons[id].open;
    setButtons(newButtons);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map(({ open }, idx) => (
        <button key={idx} onClick={() => handleOpen(idx)}>
          {open ? 'Открыто' : 'Закрыто'}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Если не хотите переходить на последнюю версию реакта, то можно поступить следующим образом:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    buttons: [
      { open: false },
      { open: false },
      { open: false },
      { open: false }
    ]
  };

  handleOpen = id => {
    const { buttons } = this.state;
    buttons[id].open = !buttons[id].open;
    this.setState({ buttons });
  };

  render() {
    const { buttons } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {buttons.map(({ open }, idx) => (
          <button key={idx} onClick={() => this.handleOpen(idx)}>
            {open ? 'Открыто' : 'Закрыто'}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Что будете делать, если таких кнопок будет 50 штук? Для каждого прописывать `open: false`?

Comment: @meine разумеется можно использовать массив или объект. Пример решает другую проблему 

Comment: Всё же я думаю, что стоит не только решить задачу, но и "сделать задел на будущее".